# jhipster on openshift: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: docker, openshift, jhipster

When i deploy my jhipster app to openshift it fails with

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile //app.war
```

which is not suprising since entrypoint.sh contains

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s..." && sleep 
${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}
exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar 
"${HOME}/app.war" "$@"
```

`${HOME}` does not contain the expeced `/home/jhipster` value because openshift uses a random user id so the jar could not be found.

I generated the configuraten with `jhipster openshift` but the Dockerfile does not fit in this context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would offer 2 options.

---

**Option #1:**
Set in the deployment `securityContext.runAsUser: <the UID of the jhipster user>`

In general, this is related to [Security Context Constraints (SCCs)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/security/deployment.html#security-deployment-sccs).

To discover the UID of the jhipster user, get a shell inside the container and execute

```
id jhipster
```

If you cannot get a shell because the container wouldn't come up due to the Java application not starting up, add this to the deployment config for the container:

```
command: ["sh"]
stdin: true
```

Replace sh with bash or any other shell that the image may have. Then you can drop inside the container from the OpenShift console or with `oc exec` (see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/executing_remote_commands.html#basic-usage)

---

**Option #2:** Override the startup `entrypoint.sh` script. For example, add something like this to the deployment config:

```
command: ["java"]
args: [
  "${JAVA_OPTS}",
  "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom",
  "-jar",
  "/home/jhipster/app.war"
]
```

I assume `app.war` is correct and it isn't `app.jar`.

Based on the `/home/jhipster/app.war` file permissions, though, this option may still fail.

Comment: Ok, i did not explained my point very well. The primary solution is quite simple: remove "${HOME}/" by hand and every thing works well.

I wonder why this generated files does not work together well without editing by hand. Perhaps i have to raise an issue in the jhipster project.